# Kendo UI DatePicker - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to resolve an issue I'm having with the Kendo UI datepicker control.  I'm getting a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError exception when ever I'm clicking on the calendar icon to open the popup with the dates.  In addition, the control does not display the dates the same way as in the Kendo UI demo and I cannot change the value property when selecting a date.  Any update on when this issue will be resolved?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for posting this issue. Can you reproduce it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo DatePicker for Angular component exposes such problem described in this Github thread:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/687

As it is posted there, it is fixed and a dev release will be published soon.
There are no workarounds that you can apply in order to avoid the issue. You will need to wait for the fix.